# Swing drop blocks

Tags: java, swing, grid, jpanel

I am making a simple game where a user clicks on colored blocks and all neighboring blocks of the same color disappear together. When a block disappears, all the blocks on top of it should fall and fill the empty space. How would I implement this sort of action? I could check all of the blocks in the grid, but this is a huge waste. I could also keep track of how many empty spaces are in a given column, but I think there should be a better way to implement it. Here is some code showing how I made the grid and each cell:

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel{

    private GridCell[][] grid;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 25;
    private static final Color[] COLORS = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW};
    private Random random;


    public GridPanel(int x, int y){
        random = new Random();
        grid = new GridCell[x][y];
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
                GridCell gc = new GridCell(i, j, DEFAULT_SIZE);
                Border border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.GRAY);
                gc.setBorder(border);
                gc.setBackground(COLORS[random.nextInt(COLORS.length)]);
                gbc.gridx = i;
                gbc.gridy = j;
                add(gc, gbc);
                grid[i][j] = gc;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class GridCell extends JPanel{

private int x;
private int y;
private int size;

public GridCell(int x, int y, int size){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(size, size);
}

public GridCoordinate getCoordinates(){
    return new GridCoordinate(x, y);
}

public int getCellSize(){
    return this.size;
}

}
```

Comment: I wouldnt think swing is your best bet here. Swing layouts are already challenging. Making them work in this way is going to be an uphill battle. You might want to consider using lwgl http://lwjgl.org/ or you could do the drawing yourself with the 2D drawing libraries in the JRE.

Comment: @MarkW Actually, is relatively easy, even with `GridBagLayout`, but `GridLayout` would much easier

Comment: Beware, components already have a concept of x/y, you might want to rename those variables

Answer (score 3):

The biggest stumbling block you would face is dealing with "empty" blocks.  Most layouts don't "reserve" space of unused portions of the screen.

`GridBagLayout` provides the means to obtain the `GridBagConstraints` used to lay out the original components.

```
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
//...
GridBagConstarints gbc = gbl.getConstraints(comp);
```

This provides you the means to adjust the constraints for the component, just don't forget to re-apply them....

```
gbl.setConstraints(comp, gbc);
```

What I would do is create a concept of a "blank" `GridCell`.  This is a cell that can't be clicked and is painted in a neutral color (or is transparent depending on your needs).  When you "remove" an active `GridCell`, you would replace it with a "blank" cell.

You would then need to calculate where the blank cells are and adjust the position of all the cells around them.

This would be best achieved by using a "virtual" model.  You would simply maintain the state of the game in this model (such as an `int` array for example) and when updated, simply update the actual view to match the model.

This will make it much simpler to determine where individual cells need to be arranged.

But that's just me...

**Updated**

You could also consider using a `GridLayout` and chaning the Z-Order of the components, for example...

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575372/swapping-jbutton-elements-in-java/12575713#12575713
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032140/moving-jlabel-to-a-different-place-in-the-jpanel-pacman-like-game/21032258#21032258
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834765/move-jbutton-with-keyboard-arrows-inside-a-grid-panel/16835242#16835242